# How I can change curve animation for snackbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, curve, snackbar, animationcontroller

Help me!
I need to change the default snackbar animation in flutter. And I need to change the curve animation when the snackbar appears.
I want to change the standard animation to Curves.easeOutBack.

I tried to use animation property of Snackbar but nothing happened. And
I tried to use Snackbar().withAnimation(_curve) but also nothing happened.

Comment: Hello, you should consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package called [another_flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar)

[image]

---

```
Flushbar(
  animationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
  forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.easeIn, //  Here you change the curve animation
  reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOut,//  Here you change the curve animation
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
  flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
  flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
  message: "I am Bottom Snackbar",
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
  ).show(context);
```